# Set Text Radio Button from JSON Android Studio - AlertDialog

Tags: android, json, radio-button

I have username from JSON (database). What should i do if i settext radiobutton from json ?

This is mycustom layout form_tugas.xml

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogrup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Nama"
            android:checked="true">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Nama">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton>

    </RadioGroup>
```

and this is my code

```
private void formTugas()
{

    getJson("http://192.168.43.144/TA/getUserTeknisi.php");
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_tugas,null);
    dialog.setView(dialogView);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

This is code when i get username from JSON

```
private void ambilUserTeknisi(String json) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

    int x = 1;

    for (int u = 0; u < jsonArray.length(); u++)
    {
        JSONObject ob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(u);
        String user  = ob.getString("username");

        users.add(new User(user));

        Log.d("username",""+users.get(u).getUsername());

    }
}
```

And this is my log

```
2020-01-12 16:25:15.510 15549-15549/com.example.adum D/username: Ronaldo
2020-01-12 16:25:15.510 15549-15549/com.example.adum D/username: Velguri
```

I want to set username "Ronaldo" and "Velguri" to my radio button in form_tugas.xml. What should i do ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

change your formTugas method to this:

```
 private void formTugas(){

        getJson("http://192.168.43.144/TA/getUserTeknisi.php");
        //add your json parse method here
        ambilUserTeknisi("your json")

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_tugas,null);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        //find your view
        AppCompatRadioButton radio1= (AppCompatRadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        AppCompatRadioButton radio2= (AppCompatRadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        //set text to your view
        radio1.settext(users.get(0).name); //set name from your user object 
        radio2.settext(users.get(1).name);

        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: form_tugas.xml is my custom layout. i have tried your code but my app has crashed. If i add my code setContentView(R.layout.form_tugas); in method form tugas, it's worked, but it has not shown as alert dialog. What should i do ?

Comment: in third line you need to pass your json to parse data. can you send your crash here to help you?

Comment: this is my logcat

Comment: 2020-01-12 19:00:02.152 29051-29051/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.adum-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.adum-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

Comment: i think my app crash because of that. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: your crash doesn't relate to this code. try clean your project from build menu  and then run your app again. if my answer is helpful use upvote button and if your problem is solved mark answer .